# How to select a specific word from the python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I will create a dictionary and enter a few words.Thus, I will search in the dictionary. For example, when i will searching “pie”, the program should display all items whose name includes ‘pie’. Also, the program should accept both uppercase and lowercase letters. How can i do?

```
desserts = {"pecan pie": "1", "pumpkin pie": "2", "cheesecake": "3", "waffle": "4"}
```

Comment: Please show us your code. SO is not a free coding service. Edit: Seems, it is. So no homework for you this weekend .

Answer (score 0):

You can either check for existence within the string or use regex:

Using `str.lower`:

```
desserts = {"pecan pie": "1", "pumpkin pie": "2", "cheesecake": "3", "waffle": "4"}
pie_desserts = [(a, b) for a, b in desserts.items() if 'pie' in a.lower()]
```

Output:

```
[('pecan pie', '1'), ('pumpkin pie', '2')]
```

Regex:

```
import re
pie_desserts = [(a, b) for a, b in desserts.items() if re.findall('pie',  a, flags=re.IGNORECASE)]
```

Output:

```
[('pecan pie', '1'), ('pumpkin pie', '2')]
```

Comment: This is the easy solution but really a hash table (dictionary) is the wrong data structure. The OP wants a suffix tree.

Comment: @quartata agreed, although I think that is out of the scope of this question.

Comment: @quartata A suffix tree for a cook book? How much/fast do you think they can eat?

Comment: @StefanPochmann I dunno, I have some pretty massive cookbooks :P